# Laravel 4.2 Validation Rules - Current Password Must Match DB Value

Tags: php, validation, laravel-4, bcrypt

On the password reset form the user supplies `current_password`, `password` and `password-confirmation`. Is there a way to specify in the validation rules that `current_password` (it's hash value) must match the database value?

Currently I have this:

```
$rules = array(
    'current_password' => 'required',
    'password'         => 'required|confirmed|min:22'
);
```

Thank you.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @ChrisForrence and @Ben, I came up with the following which works great! Much appreciated. Hope this will help someone else:

```
Validator::extend('hashmatch', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->$parameters[0]);
});
$messages = array(
    'hashmatch' => 'Your current password must match your account password.'
);
$rules = array(
    'current_password' => 'required|hashmatch:password',
    'password'         => 'required|confirmed|min:4|different:current_password'
);

$validation = Validator::make( Input::all(), $rules, $messages );
```

Comment: This might be helpful: [Custom validation rules](http://laravel.com/docs/validation#custom-validation-rules)

Comment: Great point! Let me give it a try and we'll take it try there. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, `bcrypt` hashes are unique (they have their own random salt incorporated) so even if you knew the user's plain text password you would't be able do a hash-to-hash comparison.

What you can do is actually check the plain text password against a `bcrypt` hash by doing `Hash::check('plain text password', 'bcrypt hash')` on your controller.

Comment: Thank you. I expect the return value of `check` is boolean -- this should help a great deal!

Comment: @user3558931 Yes, it's boolean.

Comment: Is it possible to do that in Model ?