# Simple Validation Rule inside the Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, validationrules

I refered here [Laravel 4.2 Validation Rules - Current Password Must Match DB Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830119/laravel-4-2-validation-rules-current-password-must-match-db-value)

**Here is my Rule for Password Confirmation :**

```
 public static $ruleschangepwd = array(
    'OldPassword' =>  array( 'required'),  // need to have my rule here
    'NewPassword' => 'required|confirmed|alphaNum|min:5|max:10'
    );
```

But I am having my rules in the Model

As i saw the below given custom rule in the question

```
Validator::extend('hashmatch', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
{
    return Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->$parameters[0]);
});
$messages = array(
    'hashmatch' => 'Your current password must match your account password.'
);
$rules = array(
    'current_password' => 'required|hashmatch:password',
    'password'         => 'required|confirmed|min:4|different:current_password'
);
```

**Is it possible to have rule like this ?**

```
 'OldPassword' =>  array( 'required', 'match:Auth::user()->password')
```

**Like this or Any simple custom rule than above given ?**

**Note :** As i am doing this in model i can't implement the above custom rule in my model. (or If i can, How can i do that inside the model)

### Update :

Can i use something like this

```
'OldPassword' =>  array( 'required' , 'same|Auth::user()->password'),
```

But i should

```
Hash::check('plain text password', 'bcrypt hash')
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to extend the validator with a custom rule. However it should be no problem if you have your rules inside the model. You can extend the validator anywhere and the rule will be globally available.

I recommend you add a new file to your project `app/validators.php`

Then add this line at the bottom of `app/start/global.php`

```
require app_path().'/validators.php';
```

Now inside `validators.php` define the validation rule

```
Validator::extend('match_auth_user_password', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){
    return Hash::check($value, Auth::user()->password);
}
```

(I changed the name a bit to be more descriptive. You obviously can use whatever name you like)

And after that add `match_auth_user_password` to your rules:

```
public static $ruleschangepwd = array(
    'OldPassword' =>  'required|match_auth_user_password',
    'NewPassword' => 'required|confirmed|alphaNum|min:5|max:10'
);
```