# Comparing Hashed Values to check whether it is Equal

Tags: php, laravel, hash, laravel-4

I am storing my Password as BCrypt (Laravel own way)

```
$NewValue = Hash::make(Input::get('Password'));

$OldValue = Auth::user()->password;  // Taking the value from database
if($NewValue == $OldValue)
{
return 'Both Password are equal'
}
else
{
//go for other operation
}
```

But whenever i check the if condition, I am always getting false.

What is the mistake i am doing ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel's hash function will generate a new hash every time you call `Hash::make`. Internally it calls [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) which then uses `crypt`. It will always generate a **random salt**. The salt is included in the final hash so when comparing it can be parsed and used to generate the same hash again.

To verify a password you need to use `Hash::check()` which then uses `password_verify` under the hood

```
$password = Input::get('Password');
$hashedPassword = Auth::user()->password;  // Taking the value from database

if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword))
{
    return 'Both Password are equal'
}
else
{
    //go for other operation
}
```

Comment: You're becoming my problem solver, (Learning from you) Thanks

Comment: Can you please look at this problem pls, i am waiting for this long ,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27700021/simple-validation-rule-inside-the-model

Comment: I'll take a look at it. But I'm not really the validation pro... Also 6 hours is not very long. Just be patient ;)

Comment: Yes, i Agree, let me wait and check :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Hash::check()` to verify a password against a hash.

```
Hash::check('secret', $hashedPassword);
```

[Docs - Security - Storing passwords](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#storing-passwords)

Comment: I tried **$NewValue = Hash::make(Input::get('Password'));
        if($NewValue == Hash::check('secret', Auth::user()->password))
        { return'true';} But not success**

Comment: The 'secret' is the hashed form of new value ?

Comment: the secret will the be plain text version of the password. $hashedPassword would be a hashed password to check it against. (Auth::user()->password)